# Possible to make an unique (single-product.php) page for an item?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I have added quite some html/css code into singe-product.php to show some images & text/buttons, but I want that to show for only one product in my shop and have all other items show the standard product page, is this somehow possible?

I have put everything I added in a div called <*div id="custom"*> <*/div*> in singe-product.php what is next? :D

Answer (score 0):

If I clearly understand what you want, you need to create a custom php page for your product, since it won't be used for any other products that you have. Call the product on the page by setting it a specific taxonomy or category.

You can find further informations here : https://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-woocommerce-excelling-ecommerce-a-custom-single-product-template

hope it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have copied the "single-product.php" into your theme directory (and not directly modifying the woocommerce's original template file). Well, into your "single-product.php" you can check for the specific product's slug and then display your custom code. Some thing like this...

```
<?php
if($post->post_name == 'your-product-slug'){
?>
<div id="custom"> </div>
<?php
}
?>
```

This way all your custom code/styles etc. will be displayed only for that specific product and for all others theme's default layout will be displayed.

Hope this helps.